# prevent drag drop on particular column using slickgrid

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am using slick grid 2.0 and I want to prevent drag drop on a few columns and prevent column reordering of those columns ( fixed column position).

I am able to do this with slight modifications in Slickgrid.js by passing the column names to the setupColumnReorder() function. But is there any other way to do this instead of modifying core files like Slickgrid.js?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about removing the possibility of user doing a column reorder? If that is what you are trying to achieve you can use this property `enableColumnReorder: false` inside your list of `options` for example:

```
var options = {
  editable: true,
  enableAddRow: true,
  enableCellNavigation: true,
  asyncEditorLoading: true,
  forceFitColumns: false,
  topPanelHeight: 25,
  enableColumnReorder: false
};
```

This blocks the reordering of all columns

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply..But i want to prevent drag drop/reorder on a few columns only (not on whole grid)..

Comment: Did you find an answer to it ?